# the "funk" sound when hitting escape key in app

Tags: swift, xcode

hello when I make an app in Xcode I always get the 
"funk" noise when I hit escape key
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNK5t.jpg

it doesn't happen in regular Mac OS apps unless I'm hitting escape in en empty textfield

but in Xcode built app it does it whenever I'm in the app and I hit escape

is there a way to override something and prevent that noise

```
    super.keyDown(with: event)
```

maybe something that has to do with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new file, cocoa class to your project, click next, create a `CustomView` class, subclass of `NSView` (language Swift). Override the method `performKeyEquivalent` and add `return event.keyCode == 53`. Then select your window view in your IB, go to the identity inspector and change the custom class to `CustomView`:

```
import Cocoa

class CustomView: NSView {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return event.keyCode == 53
    }
}
```

Comment: when I try to add CustomView to the identity inspector it won't accept it

Comment: You need to click the View in the left then click the dropdown menu in the inspector it should be already there.

Comment: when I do that I don't see it but, I did got it to work by using "NSWindow" instead of nsview

Comment: is it better to use nsview with custom view than nswindow with custom window

Comment: i  just noticted that using that method, disable cmd+ a in my textfield is there a way around this?

Comment: try `return event.keyCode == 53` instead of `return true`

Comment: works, can you explain why you can return that even.keycode == 54 statement as a bool in that case?

Comment: This will evaluate to true only for the escape key. Btw don't forget to vote it up :)

Comment: voted it up, so basicly you can return anything that is eithera  false or true statement in a boolean return?

Comment: Yes you can return anything that returns a Bool as result.